# Rounding off a list of numbers to a user-defined step while preserving their sum

Tags: objective-c, c, floating-point, integer, rounding

I've been reading a lot of posts about rounding off numbers, but I couldn't manage to do what I want :

I have got a list of positive floats.
The *unsigned integer* **roundOffStep** to use is user-defined. I have no control other it.

I want to be able to do the most accurate rounding while preserving the sum of those numbers, or at least while keeping the new sum inferior to the original sum.

How would I do that ? I am terrible with algorithms, so this is way too tricky for me.

Thx.

EDIT : Adding a Test case :

```
FLOATS
   29.20
   18.25
   14.60
   8.76
   2.19
```

sum = 73;

Let's say roundOffStep = 5;

```
ROUNDED FLOATS
30
15
15
10
0
```

sum = 70  < 73 OK

Comment: What's the meaning of `roundOffStep`?

Comment: roundOffStep is the step used to round off the numbers.

Comment: Why does 8.76 round to 5 and not 10 in your example?

Comment: Well that is the trick. if you round it to 10, then the sum is 75, which is wrong because it is not supposed to be higher than 73. But there's probably a way to get more accurate rounding while respecting this rule. I just don't know what that rule is...^^

Comment: Wouldn't most accurate be 18.25 -> 15 instead of 8.76 -> 5 ?

Comment: Well, yes, you are right. I'll edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Round all numbers to the nearest multiple of `roundOffStep` normally.
2. If the new sum is lower than the original sum, you're done.
3. For each number, calculate `rounded_number - original_number`. Sort this list of differences in decreasing order so that you can find the numbers with the largest difference.
4. Pick the number that gives the largest difference `rounded_number - original_number`, and subtract `roundOffStep` from that number.
5. Repeat step 4 (picking the next largest difference each time) until the new sum is less than the original.

This process should ensure that the rounded numbers are as close as possible to the originals, without going over the original sum.

Example, with `roundOffStep = 5`:

```
    Original Numbers  |   Rounded  |  Difference
----------------------+------------+--------------
         29.20        |     30     |     0.80
         18.25        |     20     |     1.75
         14.60        |     15     |     0.40
         8.76         |     10     |     1.24
         2.19         |     0      |    -2.19
----------------------+------------+--------------
Sum:     73           |     75     |
```

The sum is too large, so we pick the number giving the largest difference (18.25 which was rounded to 20) and subtract 5 to give 15. Now the sum is 70, so we're done.